# How notification system works

Tags: javascript, php

I am going to develop a admin tasking system using PHP, MySQL, JavaScript . How the notification system works and how they save real time data. is there there any example of notification system .

Comment: 2 ways at the monent in my head: 1st - via Ajax (asking server every N seconds), and 2nd way - via php loop inside iframe.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you have any example ? please

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this on the internet, stack overflow isn't the place to ask for links though. SO is for issues with coding.

Comment: I see actually I am very new here.

Comment: Take a look at these two pages, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
 http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher (https://pusher.com/) is great when it comes to real time, and it's not expensive.
I've been using it on a project of mine for chat, and it worked flawlessly.

They also have tutorials, and particularly, they have one on how to create real time notifications. Here's the link: https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications

I think this is perfect for you. It's simple, and while you're building your system, it's free.